Geometry question regarding two squares
I am working on a geometry problem, on which I am currently struggling:

Given a square $ABCD$ in the plane. Let $P$ be any point on the side $CD$. With the side $AP$, another square $q$ is then chosen so that the point $B$ is not in the interior and not on the edge of $q$. The corner point diagonally opposite the corner point $A$ in $q$ is called $R$ (see figure).

a) Prove that for every point $P$ on the line segment $CD$ there is exactly one square $q$ that satisfies the given conditions.
b) Determine the set of all points $R$ that can be constructed in the manner described.

My attempts on solving the problems:
I have already solved part (a) with the Pythagorean Theorem.
Now part (b) is upsetting me, I know from drawing some squares, that the set of all points is exactly (see picture) is simply the distance $q$ on the second picture (the set of all points $R$) and it is obvious, however I am unsure on how to prove it and Pythagoras might get to the solution another time.

Could someone help me out?

Given the analytic-geometry tag ... Have you described things with coordinates? I suggest focusing on the path $APR$; ie, how is getting from $P$ to $R$ related to getting from $A$ to $P$?

By set of all points R, what do you mean? Do you want an equation that generalises the coordinates of R?

@Gwen yeah exactly I suppose that is meant

@Blue I suppose that you might solve it with coordinates, but I haven‘t gotten that far

@EnktEnktson in that case you'll get an equation that requires the knowledge of the coordinates of P as well. Does you answer include that?

If you build a triangle that has the side of the square on FC from any point P on DC you will use congruent right angle triangles that has the same hypotenuse.
